# How to show `repo` in `uberSVN Web GUI` when `create repo` with `command line`

Tags: svn, command-line, load, repository, ubersvn

I use ubersvn

I create repo `svnadmin create repositories/SVN`

I load dumpfile to new repo `svnadmin load repositories/SVN/ < backups/SVN-rev1-15.dump`

But when I create and load finished then view in [UberSVN GUI](http://hostname:9890/ubersvn/views/platform/repository/viewRepositories.jsf) don't see new repo show here.
So, how to create repo with command line show in [Repositories uberSVN GUI](http://hostname:9890/ubersvn/views/platform/repository/viewRepositories.jsf)

Note: I want to use only command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short you can't create a repo via command line and see it in uberSVN without importing it.

You would need to create it in command line, then go to uberSVN and click 'add repository' and choose 'add an existing repository located on the server'. There's documentation on this [here](http://docs.ubersvn.com/v1.0/reference.html#R31).

Alternatively, just create the repository directly in uberSVN.